# Having issues with guitar percussion

Tags: guitar, strings, percussion

I have started learning percussive techniques on the guitar. While I can reproduce these on my teacher's guitar without issues, I can't do the same on my own guitar. My teacher recommended that I change the strings, which I did, but I still can't achieve the same effect.

What should I do? Are the strings too high up from the neck? Do I need to rechange them or is the best course of action just to take them into the shop and ask there?

EDIT: Sorry for the lack of detail – I am trying to try percussive techniques like a muted slap, similar to these:

- muted slap

- slapping

- or the slapping thumb technique

I try these techniques on my own guitar, and the sound is nowhere near as loud and "crunchy" as my teacher's guitar, where I can make the sound ring out clearly. On my own guitar, it makes a slight noise, but it takes a ton of effort and force and I have to jam my fingers onto the strings and push very hard against the stiff strings to make any noise.

Teacher tried the techniques on my guitar and was surprised. He couldn't make the noise ring out either and suggested I change my strings. I have now, and it hasn't made a difference.

Comment: What specific techniques are not working on your guitar and what results are you getting when you try them? Has your teacher tried the techniques on your guitar and if so, what did they say about it?

Comment: @DoktorMayhem - Turns out that the instructor *can* do it on his guitar but not the OP's: "Teacher tried the techniques on my guitar and was surprised. He couldn't make the noise ring out either and suggested I change my strings."

Answer (score 1):

The distance between the strings and the 12th fret is called "the action" ([around 1/16" (1.6mm)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(music)#Adjusting_the_action)). This distance can be modified with the guitar truss rod (a long screw going trough the neck) or by filling the saddle or the nut. This being said, it has to be performed by a luthier.

A aspect of the guitar that will make a big difference in the sound is the wood that was used to make the guitar, some wood sounds better (no pun intended).

Also what kind of guitars are you talking about? Acoustic with metal strings or classic with nylon strings. (just in case, because I have seen this, don't put metal strings on a classic guitar as it's neck is not made for the tension a metal strings create and bend the neck thus the action gets bigger)